# Python Redis - RuntimeError pubsub connection not set

Tags: python, redis, celery

**Version**:  redis-py=3.1.0  and redis=3.2.10

**Platform**:  Python 2.7.5 / CentOS Linux release 7.4.1708 (Core)

**Infrastructure**:

- two machines (worker1, worker2 ) for running celery worker services with default concurrency (=8).
- one dedicated machine (redis1) for running redis server.

**Issue**:

After the workers running for some time, suddenly a worker running on `machine1` dies due to a `RuntimeError` raised losing a connection to pubsub.

`machine1.worker.log`

```
[2019-02-01 13:43:39,477: CRITICAL/MainProcess] Unrecoverable error: RuntimeError(u'pubsub connection not set: did you forget to call subscribe() or psubscribe()?',)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/c1/cip-middleware/webapp/virtualenv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/celery/worker/worker.py", line 205, in start
    self.blueprint.start(self)
  File "/opt/c1/cip-middleware/webapp/virtualenv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/celery/bootsteps.py", line 119, in start
    step.start(parent)
  File "/opt/c1/cip-middleware/webapp/virtualenv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/celery/bootsteps.py", line 369, in start
    return self.obj.start()
  File "/opt/c1/cip-middleware/webapp/virtualenv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/celery/worker/consumer/consumer.py", line 322, in start
    blueprint.start(self)
  File "/opt/c1/cip-middleware/webapp/virtualenv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/celery/bootsteps.py", line 119, in start
    step.start(parent)
  File "/opt/c1/cip-middleware/webapp/virtualenv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/celery/worker/consumer/consumer.py", line 598, in start
    c.loop(*c.loop_args())
  File "/opt/c1/cip-middleware/webapp/virtualenv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/celery/worker/loops.py", line 91, in asynloop
    next(loop)
  File "/opt/c1/cip-middleware/webapp/virtualenv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/kombu/asynchronous/hub.py", line 354, in create_loop
    cb(*cbargs)
  File "/opt/c1/cip-middleware/webapp/virtualenv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/kombu/transport/redis.py", line 1047, in on_readable
    self.cycle.on_readable(fileno)
  File "/opt/c1/cip-middleware/webapp/virtualenv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/kombu/transport/redis.py", line 344, in on_readable
    chan.handlers[type]()
  File "/opt/c1/cip-middleware/webapp/virtualenv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/kombu/transport/redis.py", line 674, in _receive
    ret.append(self._receive_one(c))
  File "/opt/c1/cip-middleware/webapp/virtualenv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/kombu/transport/redis.py", line 685, in _receive_one
    response = c.parse_response()
  File "/opt/c1/cip-middleware/webapp/virtualenv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/redis/client.py", line 3032, in parse_response
    'pubsub connection not set: '
RuntimeError: pubsub connection not set: did you forget to call subscribe() or psubscribe()?
```

While at the same time I have spotted that worker running on `machine2` suffers due to not being able to connect to `redis`. Eventually, it managed to recover and reconnect to `redis` and receiving the queued tasks.

`machine2.worker.log`

```
[2019-02-01 14:43:41,722: WARNING/MainProcess] consumer: Connection to broker lost. Trying to re-establish the connection...
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/c1/cip-middleware/webapp/virtualenv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/celery/worker/consumer/consumer.py", line 322, in start
    blueprint.start(self)
  File "/opt/c1/cip-middleware/webapp/virtualenv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/celery/bootsteps.py", line 119, in start
    step.start(parent)
  File "/opt/c1/cip-middleware/webapp/virtualenv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/celery/worker/consumer/mingle.py", line 40, in start
    self.sync(c)
  File "/opt/c1/cip-middleware/webapp/virtualenv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/celery/worker/consumer/mingle.py", line 44, in sync
    replies = self.send_hello(c)
  File "/opt/c1/cip-middleware/webapp/virtualenv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/celery/worker/consumer/mingle.py", line 57, in send_hello
    replies = inspect.hello(c.hostname, our_revoked._data) or {}
  File "/opt/c1/cip-middleware/webapp/virtualenv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/celery/app/control.py", line 143, in hello
    return self._request('hello', from_node=from_node, revoked=revoked)
  File "/opt/c1/cip-middleware/webapp/virtualenv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/celery/app/control.py", line 95, in _request
    timeout=self.timeout, reply=True,
  File "/opt/c1/cip-middleware/webapp/virtualenv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/celery/app/control.py", line 454, in broadcast
    limit, callback, channel=channel,
  File "/opt/c1/cip-middleware/webapp/virtualenv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/kombu/pidbox.py", line 315, in _broadcast
    serializer=serializer)
  File "/opt/c1/cip-middleware/webapp/virtualenv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/kombu/pidbox.py", line 290, in _publish
    serializer=serializer,
  File "/opt/c1/cip-middleware/webapp/virtualenv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/kombu/messaging.py", line 181, in publish
    exchange_name, declare,
  File "/opt/c1/cip-middleware/webapp/virtualenv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/kombu/messaging.py", line 203, in _publish
    mandatory=mandatory, immediate=immediate,
  File "/opt/c1/cip-middleware/webapp/virtualenv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/kombu/transport/virtual/base.py", line 605, in basic_publish
    message, exchange, routing_key, **kwargs
  File "/opt/c1/cip-middleware/webapp/virtualenv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/kombu/transport/virtual/exchange.py", line 151, in deliver
    exchange, message, routing_key, **kwargs)
  File "/opt/c1/cip-middleware/webapp/virtualenv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/kombu/transport/redis.py", line 781, in _put_fanout
    dumps(message),
  File "/opt/c1/cip-middleware/webapp/virtualenv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/redis/client.py", line 2716, in publish
    return self.execute_command('PUBLISH', channel, message)
  File "/opt/c1/cip-middleware/webapp/virtualenv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/redis/client.py", line 775, in execute_command
    return self.parse_response(connection, command_name, **options)
  File "/opt/c1/cip-middleware/webapp/virtualenv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/redis/client.py", line 789, in parse_response
    response = connection.read_response()
  File "/opt/c1/cip-middleware/webapp/virtualenv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/redis/connection.py", line 636, in read_response
    raise e
ConnectionError: Error while reading from socket: (u'Connection closed by server.',)
[2019-02-01 14:44:50,237: INFO/MainProcess] Received task: c1_cip_middleware.tasks.validate_purchases.run_purchases_validation[a411dd90-ab50-4101-becb-90adda3663a2]
```

*** Questions ***

I wonder what are the circumstances/scenarios when `RuntimeError` is raised, thus, the worker gets into the "unrecovery" stage and must be stopped?

I am in doubt what could be a root-cause of having this issue, especially that one worker managed to recover but the other one just died?